# How does implicit conversion work in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how implicit conversion works.
I have 3 functions

```
Foo(int, int)
Foo(short, short)
Foo(short, unsigned char)
```

Then I call

```
Foo(unsigned char, unsigned char)
```

and `Foo(int, int)` is called. Can somebody explain how it works?

Comment: There should be ample explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Depends on what angle you are actually asking about. "how it works" is kinda broad.

Comment: And there's also the problem of this in fact [being ambiguous](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/073f1c74bd29e280). What compiler are you using?

Comment: GCC seems to compile with a warning https://godbolt.org/g/PjjDwY.

Comment: I've actually got the same warnings too. But MinGW compiled it, so I'm now interested how it works inside.

Comment: @DeiDei - GCC "fixes" it as an extension (read the warning text). It's not a portable call.

Comment: Check these pages http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion, you'll find plenty of information regarding overload resolution and ranking of implicit conversion sequences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR;** This is *ill-formed* according to the standard, which is why you get warnings/errors when compiling with gcc/clang. There is an ambiguity between the first and the third call because the implicit conversion sequence from `unsigned char` to `short` is worse than the one from `unsigned char` to `int` (first one is a conversion while the second one is a promotion).

---

You have to consider 3 different implicit conversion sequences in this example, each one containing a single standard conversion:

- `unsigned char` to `unsigned char`, which is an **exact match**.
- `unsigned char` to `short` which is an integral **conversion**.
- `unsigned char` to `int` which is an integral **promotion**.

The ranking of the conversion sequences is a follows:

**exact match** > **integral promotion** > **integral conversion**

For an overload `FooA` to be better than an overload `FooB`, implicit conversions for all arguments of `FooA` have to be *not worse* than implicit conversions for arguments of `FooB`, and at least one of the implicit conversion for `FooA` must be *better* than the corresponding conversion for `FooB`.

In your case:

- `Foo(int, int)` vs. `Foo(short, short)` — First one is better because `unsigned char` to `int` (promotion) is better than `unsigned char` to `short` (conversion).
- `Foo(int, int)` vs. `Foo(short, unsigned char)` — This is ambiguous:

  - `unsigned char` to `int` is better than `unsigned char` to `short`.
  - `unsigned char` to `int` is worse than `unsigned char` to `unsigned char`.
- `Foo(short, short)` vs. `Foo(short, unsigned char)` — Second one is better because `unsigned char` to `unsigned char` (exact match) is better than `unsigned char` to `short` (conversion).

There is an ambiguity only between `Foo(int, int)` and `Foo(short, unsigned char)`, the second overload `Foo(short, short)` does not participate in the "ambiguity". If you remove either the first or the third overload, the ambiguity disappears and the first or the third overload is chosen.

Comment: Thanks! This makes it more clearly. But why is

`uchar -> int` promotion

and

`uchar -> short` conversion?

Comment: @Livace Because the standard says so. ^^' I guess it's because you don't want to have multiple promotions from a type to avoid weird rankings in some case, but I am not enough expert to give you a concrete example.

Comment: Re: "This should not compile..." -- note that the language definition does not impose that constraint. The only requirement is that the compiler must **issue a diagnostic**; having done that, the compiler is free to do whatever the implementor wants, including producing code that does something that the implementor believes is sensible.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right, I've changed the phrasing using *ill-formed* which is, I think, correct here.